# How can I control the "value" or content of a button using CSS (perhaps as a style) or through javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, button

Is there a way one can use CSS or javascript to control not only the button style, but what the button actually says.  I've seen many "CSS button creator" tools out there, but they all require html, or a portion of the code that requires "PUSH HERE".

(update)
Thank you all for your input.
Let me explain more of the big picture.  In short, we are using third party to control the ecommerce end of our site. We have a css override file that we can use to control a lot of what the site displays.

Here is a rough example of a button:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Buford/yLSHT/

```
<style type="text/css">
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

`<body><a href="#" class="btn">PUSH ME</a></body>`

Is there a way we can update the html code "PUSH ME" to where it can be a variable controlled by means of CSS or Javascript?

Comment: CSS can control the button style. Javascript can control what the button says. You can use Javascript to create the button entirely too, which means no requirement of adding any HTML. All this is easily Googled.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, especially if the button element is blank.

Here's HTML:

```
<button></button>
```

And, CSS:

```
button:before {
    content: "Click me";
}
```

And fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3aZkt/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using Javascript:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="button" id="button1"/>
```

Javascript Code:

```
document.getElementById('button1').value='This is button';
```